# Using pandas, how can I sort a table on all values that contains a string element from a list of string elements?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of strings looking like this:

```
strings = ['apple', 'pear', 'grapefruit']
```

and I have a data frame containing id and text values like this:

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | The grapefruit is delicious! But the pear tastes awful. |
| 2 | I am a big fan og apple products |
| 3 | The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog |
| 4 | An apple a day keeps the doctor away |

Using pandas I would like to create a filter which will give me only the id and values for those rows, which contain one or more of the values together with a column, showing which values are contained in the string, like this:

| id | value | value contains substrings: |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | The grapefruit is delicious! But the pear tastes awful. | grapefruit, pear |
| 2 | I am a big fan og apple products | apple |
| 4 | An apple a day keeps the doctor away | apple |

**How would I write this using pandas?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html):

```
df['fruits'] = df['value'].str.findall('|'.join(strings)).str.join(', ')
df[df.fruits != '']

   id                                              value            fruits
0   1  The grapefruit is delicious! But the pear tast...  grapefruit, pear
1   2                   I am a big fan og apple products             apple
3   4               An apple a day keeps the doctor away             apple
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Psidom. Can you please explain to me what the purpose is of the pipe and why it is needed?

Comment: It creates a regular expression from  your `strings` list. Which means OR, i.e. either of the string match from  the list.

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you! How can I prevent the fruits column from writing the fruit for each time it occurs in the text? e.g. "I love apple apple" will output "apple, apple" in the fruit column

Comment: `df['value'].str.findall('|'.join(strings)).apply(set).str.join(', ')` use `.apply(set)` to remove duplicates.